# Category inline-block "buttons" in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been wondering if it is possible to make a row of blocks, which never go below each other and adjust line-height so that text within always remain in the middle of those blocks, no matter the amount of content (and when really necesarry, adjust the height of the blocks themselves). I would want to make it look somewhat like the following code:

```css
ul
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li
{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a
{
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #009ec3;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover
{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 6</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 7</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 8</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 9</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 10</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 11</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 12</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 13</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using Bootstrap's `.col-md-1` class but that only goes up to 12 blocks and I got at least 13 or more. Would there be a way to achieve this in Bootstrap and if so, how would I do this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/892sfauL/)

**Edit:** I am trying to center the text within the category buttons and initally the former stylesheet made use of the flexbox property to do this (as line-height won't do the job for multiple lines of text). The problem about flexbox is that it is not compatible with older browser versions and I would like to achieve this for e.g. IE9 aswell. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to fix that within the following code used in this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1axjw8x/)?

Comment: Not exactly or automatically..you'd need media queries to adjust the heights...unless you **want** scrollbars?

Comment: No scroll bars please @Paulie_D

Comment: Then you would need to adjust the heights / sizes in the Bootstrap media queries. ...

Comment: Frankly though, no-one wants to see a menu that is 25 items wide...consider restructuring to dropdowns or columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could use swiper js to add a nice interaction. The items will be freely draggable.

[**Swiper.Js**](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.Vv1QctUrKUk)

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    freeMode: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
});
```

Check the fiddle and drag the items.

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/c0g1zLta/1/

Comment: This might be a good solution. Any idea on how I would always center text within those blocks, and make it always fit within them (maybe make the blocks bigger when content does so aswell)?

Answer (score -1):

maybe use percentage instead of pixel.
or if you want use more column in grid system of bootstrap, go http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
and change this `@grid-columns:`